# Report exact p-value in stat_compare_means

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I need to report the exact p-value on a boxplot produced by `ggboxplot` for a paper, but with very small p-values, `stat_compare_means` only gives < XX. How can I get the exact p-value in place of the smallest one in the example below?

```
library(ggpubr)
data(ToothGrowth)
data_to_change <- which(ToothGrowth$dose==0.5)
ToothGrowth$len[data_to_change] <- ToothGrowth$len[data_to_change]-10


 ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len",
           color = "dose", palette = "jco")+

 stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, label = "p.format", method = "t.test")
```

[image]

Comment: The formatting of p values below 2.2e-16 is hard-coded into `stat_compare_means` and cannot be chamged. It seems very unlikely that a journal requires an exact 8-sigma p value. In any case, you could get the exact p value from running the t tests yourself and include them in your paper's text. The labels in the plot are only for illustration. Putting the exact p values on your plot is possible, but requires a lot of manual plotting of elements, which likely isn't worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

##### Your Data

One way you could achieve this is to simply change the arguments to have your own customized labels. You don't appear to have the `my_comparisons` object in your question, so I have also added that to my reproduction of your problem.

```
#### Add Comparisons ####
my_comparisons <- list( c("0.5", "1"), c("1", "2"), c("0.5", "2") )

#### Reset Arguments in List ####
ggboxplot(ToothGrowth,
          x = "dose", 
          y = "len",
          color = "dose", 
          palette = "jco")+
  stat_compare_means(label = "p.format",
                     comparisons = my_comparisons,
                     method = "t.test",
                     symnum.args = list(cutpoints = c(0, 0.05, 1), 
                                        symbols = "p < 0.05"))
```

This will label all of your sections with "p < 0.05". You also just as easily supply a vector of values for each p value.

[image]

##### Varying P Value Data

If you don't have the same values, this may be tricky. I would instead use the `add_xy_position` function from `rstatix` and relabel the p value labels, then add them to the plot, like I show below.

```
#### Load Packages ####
library(datarium)
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)

#### Pivot Data to Long Format ####
anx <- anxiety %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("t"),
               names_to = "treatment",
               values_to = "outcome") 

#### Create Tukey with Manual Labels on XY Positions ####
tuke <- anx %>% 
  tukey_hsd(
    outcome ~ treatment
  ) %>% 
  add_xy_position() %>% 
  mutate(p.adj.signif = c("p = .09",
                          "p < .05",
                          "p < .05"))

#### Plot Them ####
anx %>% 
  ggboxplot(
    x = "treatment",
    y = "outcome",
    palette = "lancet",
    color = "treatment"
  )+
  stat_pvalue_manual(tuke,
                     step.increase = .2)
```

[image]